# Undoing add_action when setup within a plugin class

Tags: wordpress

I've inherited the following setup with a PHP problem I'd appreciate thoughts on: we're using the Customer Reviews for WooCommerce plugin by ivole with WooCommerce Bookings by Automattic.

Customer Revierws for WooCommerce contains the following class constructor which sets up an action to send an email to a customer when a order has been completed (i.e. paid for in this case):

```
class Ivole_Sender {
    public function __construct() {
        :
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array( $this, 'sender_trigger' ) );
        :
    }
    :
}
```

Problem is, because a booking isn't complete until the date attached the booking has past, it actually needs to attach to a different action:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_booking_complete', array( $this, 'sender_trigger' ) );
```

Typically, using `remove_action` in function.php (or similar), and then re-adding the action would be fine, but in this case, as the `add_action` happens within the class, how do I `remove_action` without physically modifying the class in the plugin?

Plugin load order looks like this:

**ivole.php (plugin loader):**

```
require_once( 'class-ivole.php' );
```

**class-ivole.php:**

```
require_once('class-ivole-sender.php');
```

**class-ivole-sender.php:**

```
class Ivole_Sender {
    public function __construct() {
        :
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array( $this, 'sender_trigger' ) );
        :
    }
    :
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find where the class is instantiate like this :

```
$ivole_sender = new Ivole_Sender();
```

So you can use this variable in the remove action.

```
global $ivole_sender;
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array( $ivole_sender, 'sender_trigger' ), 10 );
```

Comment: And them presumably add the new action in the same way? `add_action( 'woocommerce_booking_complete', array( $ivole_sender, 'sender_trigger' ) )`